# Unix domain socket : Make Latency constant

Tags: c, linux, sockets, datagram, unix-socket

**Issue summary: AF_UNIX stable sending, bursty receiving.**

I have an application B that receives data over unix domain datagram socket. There is peer application A that sends data to it. Both A and B are running continuously (and are SCHED_FIFO). My application A also prints the time of reception.

The peer application B can send data at varying timings (varying in terms of milliseconds only). Ideally (what I expect) the packet send delay should exactly match with reception delay. For example:

```
A sends in time            :  5ms     10ms      15ms     21ms   30ms   36ms
B should receive in time   :  5+x ms  10+x ms   15+x ms  21+x ms ...
```

Where x is a constant delay.

But when I experimented what I observe in B is :

```
A sends in time            :  5ms     10ms      15ms     21ms   30ms   36ms
B received in time         :  5+w ms  10+x ms   15+y ms  21+z ms ...
```

(w,x,y,z are different constant delays). So I cannot predict reception time when sending time is given).

Is it because some buffering is involved in unix domain socket ? Please suggest some  workaround for the issue so that the reception time is predicable from send time. I need 1 millisecond accuracy.

(I am using vanilla Linux 3.0 kernel)

Comment: note: I got one tweak-able parameter /proc/sys/net/unix/max_dgram_qlen, which can be set to 1. But still there is issue. Might be scheduling delay also.

Comment: Is it UDP or is it Unix Domain socket?  It cannot be both.  Also, why do you need 1 millisecond accuracy?  What if it isn't feasible?  Is your recv() blocking or non-blocking?

Comment: @John I meant AF_UNIX and SOCK_DGRAM both

Comment: My receive and send both are blocking.

Comment: I'm not sure why it should matter with a Unix Domain socket but have you disabled Nagle's algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm

Comment: @dave. The nagle's algorithm is not applicable for SOCK_DGRAM .It is for TCP.

Comment: After A sends data to B, what does A do? Does it immediately send again, or is it waiting for something? Do you call `usleep()` or something to achieve the 5 ms gap, or is that just to help you to illustrate the issue?

Comment: Mostly the example is to illustrate. The actual case the data is audio. While playing back, B derives timing out of packet reception. I didn't want to mention those since that will attract out of focus discussions.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using blocking recv(), when no datagram is available your program will be unscheduled.  This is bad for your use case--you want your program to stay hot.  So make your recv() non-blocking, and handle EAGAIN by simply busy waiting.  This will consume 100% of one core, but I think you'll find it helps you achieve your goal.

Comment: seems one of the candidate ideas. But I cannot keep my CPU busy :-(

Comment: So you want high accuracy, low latency, but can't keep the CPU busy?  Good luck.  :)

Comment: Thanks John :-) . But let me give a try.

Comment: I don't understand how context switching overhead could account for over a millisecond of jitter unless his system is swapping or the run queue in the scheduler is very long.